# how to keep a "Hello World" type server running

Tags: java, sockets, io, stream, client-server

How do I keep the server "open" so that it can send and receive objects on a continuing basis without crashing?  Basically, I would like to put an infinite loop around the `readRecord` method, so that it runs indefinitely.

server:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.driver;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());
    private final RecordQueue recordsQueue = new RecordQueue();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
        new Server().readRecord(portNumber);
    }

    public void readRecord(int portNumber) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
        MyRecord recordFromClient = null;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        while (true) {
            try {
                recordFromClient = (MyRecord) objectInputStream.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(recordFromClient);
        }
    }
}
```

client:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.driver;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Client {

    private List<MyRecord> iterate() {
        MyRecord myRecord = null;
        List<MyRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            myRecord = new MyRecord(i, "foo");
            records.add(myRecord);
        }
        return records;
    }

    public void simple(String server, int portNumber) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket s = new Socket(server, portNumber);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        List<MyRecord> records = iterate();
        for (MyRecord record : records) {
            oos.writeObject(record);
        }
        oos.flush();
        Object received = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(received);
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
        String server = (props.getProperty("server"));
        new Client().simple(server, portNumber);
    }
}
```

server output:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -jar NetBeansProjects/Server/dist/Server.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1285)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1230)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1426)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1576)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
    at net.bounceme.dur.driver.Server.readRecord(Server.java:32)
    at net.bounceme.dur.driver.Server.main(Server.java:16)
thufir@dur:~$
```

client output:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -jar NetBeansProjects/Client/dist/Client.jar 
value=0, id='foo
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay what your problem is, your server was made to only read and handle one object at a time. So When you client tries to send all of those MyRecord objects, the server reads one, and then tries to send it back to you, the problem is, you are still trying to send the other MyRecord objects while the server is trying to send you the FIRST MyRecord object. Client/Server connections are like a game of tennis. One person must serve the ball to the other player, and the other must then hit the ball back. You cannot both hit a ball with neither of you recieving.

So in,

```
    for (MyRecord record : records) {
        oos.writeObject(record);
    }
    oos.flush();
    Object received = ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(received);
```

you should put the

```
    oos.flush();
    Object received = ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(received);
```

inside of the `for()` loop, that way each `MyRecord` object is sent to the server, read by the server, sent back to the client by the server, and read by the client.

Final result:

```
    for (MyRecord record : records) {
        oos.writeObject(record);
        oos.flush();
        Object received = ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(received);
    }
```

Comment: on reflection, one object at a time is fine.  I just want to log objects which the server receives at this juncture.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the changes(i edited some code to run on my machine, so make your changes appropriately)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class MyRecord implements java.io.Serializable
{
int x;
String y;
MyRecord(int a,String b)
{
x=a;
y=b;
}
}

class Server {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());
//private final RecordQueue recordsQueue = new RecordQueue();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
    //int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
    new Server().readRecord(2*1000);
}

public void readRecord(int portNumber) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
    MyRecord recordFromClient = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    while (true) {
        try {
            recordFromClient = (MyRecord) objectInputStream.readObject();
            if(recordFromClient.x==-1) {break;}
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(recordFromClient);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
    }
}
}  

class Client {

private List<MyRecord> iterate() {
    MyRecord myRecord = null;
    List<MyRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        myRecord = new MyRecord(i, "foo");
        records.add(myRecord);
    }
    return records;
}

public void simple(String server, int portNumber) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Socket s = new Socket(server, portNumber);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    List<MyRecord> records = iterate();
    for (MyRecord record : records) {
        oos.writeObject(record);
    oos.flush();
    Object received = ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(received);
    }
    MyRecord record= new MyRecord(-1,"end");
    oos.writeObject(record);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    ois.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
    //int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));
    String server = "localhost";
    new Client().simple(server, 2000);
}
}
```

Comment: why are you using `break`?  I updated my answer a bit, but still can't log the object which the server receives.

Comment: break because when the client is done sending the records, the server keeps reading expecting(not knowing that client has sent all records it has to) more records, so if you comment that statement, you will get an EOFException.
this was done to signal that the client is done sending objects

Answer (score 0):

This works to a degree:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.driver;

//import stuff

public class Server {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName());
    private final RecordQueue recordsQueue = new RecordQueue();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("port"));

        while (true) {
            try {
                new Server().inOut(portNumber);
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<MyRecord> dummyRecords() {
        MyRecord record = null;
        List<MyRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            record = new MyRecord(i, "foo");
            records.add(record);
            log.info(record.toString());
        }
        return records;
    }

    public void inOut(int portNumber) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        log.info("...connected...waiting for data...");
        MyRecord recordFromClient = (MyRecord) objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(recordFromClient);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectInputStream.close();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        log.info(recordFromClient.toString());//never logs
        System.out.println("never gets here");
    }
}
```

except that it never logs the `recordFromClient`, which is kind of important.  On the plus side, it doesn't crash.